# How to disable creation of DefaultService for Actor Service?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Every time I build a solution with (stateful) Actor service the service gets automatically added to ApplicationManifest.xml DefaultServices section.

How can I disable this behaviour for the services I want instantiate manually?

I've tried modifying the ServiceManifest.xml of the Actor service by removing the `<DefaultService>` tag, but it also is added back automatically with every build.

Comment: did following the msbuild route fix this issue? I find myself with the same problem

Comment: I don't know as I never tried the msbuild route. Didn't feel like wasting time on this issue as it's only a minor annoyance for me. Anyways there should exist an easier way to do this than messing with msbuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All services are automatically set to be default.  You can't disable just that functionality.  The best option would be to insert some MSBuild logic which updates the app manifest file after those undesired changes have been applied to the file.  You can have that integrated into the main packaging logic so it would automatically be executed when you publish or F5 from VS.

To do this, you can add an MSBuild target to your .sfproj file:

```
<Target Name="AfterPackage" AfterTargets="Package">
  <!-- Insert your MSBuild logic here -->
</Target>
```

By inserting your own MSBuild logic there, you can make the necessary changes you want to the app manifest file and have those changes executed implicitly whenever VS runs a package operation.  So, in your case, you can update the file to not have the service defined as a default service.  You can determine the path to the package folder by using the PackageLocation MSBuild property.